# Merge 2 arrays and created a new one

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have 2 arrays this

```
let array1 = [
    {
        designation: "SSE",
        emailId: "abc@gmail.com",
        employeeId: 1997,
        firstName: "user2",
    },
    {
        designation: "DEVELOPER",
        emailId: "ab@gmail.com",
        employeeId: 19,
        firstName: "user1",
    },
    {
        designation: "DEVELOPER",
        emailId: "ab@gmail.com",
        employeeId: 191,
        firstName: "user1",
    },
];

let array2 = [
    {
        designation: "SSE",
        emailId: "abc@gmail.com",
        employeeId: 199,
        firstName: "user2",
    },
    {
        designation: "DEVELOPER",
        emailId: "ab@gmail.com",
        employeeId: 19,
        firstName: "user1",
    },
    {
        designation: "DEVELOPER",
        emailId: "ab@gmail.com",
        employeeId: 191,
        firstName: "user1",
    },
    {
        designation: "TESTER",
        emailId: "ab@gmail.com",
        employeeId: 1221,
        firstName: "user1",
    },
];
```

See, I have some common records in both arrays and one is missing in array2. I want to merge them into one if employeeId doesn't match. Like this.

```
let array3 = [
   {employeeId: 1997, isActive: false}, 
   {employeeId: 199, isActive: true}, 
   {employeeId: 19, isActive: true}, 
   {employeeId: 191, isActive: true},
   {employeeId: 1221, isActive: false}
]
```

array3[3].isActive is false because it doesn't match in both arrays.

Comment: Can you explain why `employeeId: 199` is true and `employeeId: 1221` is false?

Comment: It is because they don't match in both arrays.

Comment: @Gajen `1997` is in `array1` but not `array2`, why is it `true`?

Comment: @Gajen `employeeId: 199` is also not matching in first array, then why it has `isActive: true`?

Comment: Yes, it should be false. Its a mistake let me correct

Comment: Still the expected result is wrong. Please correct it by comparing the logic. As per your logic, only `19` and `199` will be true since they are only the copmmon elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
let result = [];

const employeeIdArray2 = array2.map(e => e.employeeId);
const employeeIdArray1 = array1.map(e => e.employeeId);

const missingEmployeeIdArray = employeeIdArray2.length > employeeIdArray1.length ? employeeIdArray1 : employeeIdArray2;

result = array2.map(e => {
  if (missingEmployeeIdArray.includes(e.employeeId)) {
    return {
      ...e,
      isActive: true
    }
  } else {
    return {
      ...e,
      isActive: false
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This approach will not work if I have different data in array1. I think we will need to loop on both of them

Comment: @Gajen You want 2-way merge?

Answer (score 1):

1. Get an array of employeeId from `array1`
2. Get an array of employeeId from `array2`
3. Create an array with all the ([unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)) emplyeeId's
4. [Create an array with the ID's that are not matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45599749/using-filter-to-compare-two-arrays-and-return-values-that-arent-matched)
5. [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over all the ids (`array_0_ids`) to:

   1. Create an object
   2. Set `isActive` to the result of `!non_matching.includes(emplyeeId)`

```js
let array1 = [{designation: "SSE", emailId: "abc@gmail.com", employeeId: 199, firstName: "user2", }, {designation: "DEVELOPER", emailId: "ab@gmail.com", employeeId: 19, firstName: "user1", }, {designation: "DEVELOPER", emailId: "ab@gmail.com", employeeId: 191, firstName: "user1", }, ];
let array2 = [{designation: "SSE", emailId: "abc@gmail.com", employeeId: 199, firstName: "user2", }, {designation: "DEVELOPER", emailId: "ab@gmail.com", employeeId: 19, firstName: "user1", }, {designation: "DEVELOPER", emailId: "ab@gmail.com", employeeId: 191, firstName: "user1", }, {designation: "TESTER", emailId: "ab@gmail.com", employeeId: 1221, firstName: "user1", }, ];

let array_1_ids = array1.map(i => i.employeeId);
let array_2_ids = array2.map(i => i.employeeId);
let array_0_ids = [ ...array_1_ids, ...array_2_ids ].filter((v, i, s) => s.indexOf(v) === i);

let non_matching = array_2_ids.filter(id => !array_1_ids.includes(id));

let result = array_0_ids.map(emplyeeId => {
  return {
    emplyeeId,
    isActive: !non_matching.includes(emplyeeId)
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

```json
[
  {"emplyeeId": 199, "isActive": true },
  {"emplyeeId": 19, "isActive": true}, 
  {"emplyeeId": 191, "isActive": true},
  {"emplyeeId": 1221, "isActive": false} 
]
```

Comment: Please verify whether the questionaior has specified his logic correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [uniqBy method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy) from lodash.

```
const mergedArray = uniqBy([...array1, ...array2], "employeeId");
```

Check out the live example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-l3kufd?file=index.js).

Answer (score 0):

```
mergeArr = ():any[] => {
return this.array1.map(
  e => {
    if(this.array2.map(x=>x.employeeId).includes(e.employeeId)){
      return {employeeId:e.employeeId, isActive:true};
    }else{
      return {employeeId:e.employeeId, isActive:false};
    }
  }
)
```

}

This might work..

Updated one..

```
mergeArr = ():any[] => {
let addedEmployees = new Set<number>();
let arr3 =  this.array1.map(
  e => {
    addedEmployees.add(e.employeeId);
    if(this.array2.map(x=>x.employeeId).includes(e.employeeId)){
      return {employeeId:e.employeeId, isActive:true};
    }else{
      return {employeeId:e.employeeId, isActive:false};
    }
  }
)

this.array2.forEach(e => {
  if(!addedEmployees.has(e.employeeId)){
    arr3.push({employeeId:e.employeeId, isActive:false});
  }
})

return arr3;
```

}

Comment: This won't work if I have different array items in both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an object where the key will be the employeeId and the value will be the number of occurrences
2. Create the final array by iterating over the object entries, set `isActive` to true when the number of occurrences is 2.

```js
const array1 = [
  {
    designation: "SSE",
    emailId: "abc@gmail.com",
    employeeId: 199,
    firstName: "user2",
  },
  {
    designation: "DEVELOPER",
    emailId: "ab@gmail.com",
    employeeId: 19,
    firstName: "user1",
  },
  {
    designation: "DEVELOPER",
    emailId: "ab@gmail.com",
    employeeId: 191,
    firstName: "user1",
  },
];

const array2 = [
  {
    designation: "SSE",
    emailId: "abc@gmail.com",
    employeeId: 199,
    firstName: "user2",
  },
  {
    designation: "DEVELOPER",
    emailId: "ab@gmail.com",
    employeeId: 19,
    firstName: "user1",
  },
  {
    designation: "DEVELOPER",
    emailId: "ab@gmail.com",
    employeeId: 191,
    firstName: "user1",
  },
  {
    designation: "TESTER",
    emailId: "ab@gmail.com",
    employeeId: 1221,
    firstName: "user1",
  },
];

const reducer = (acc, e) => ({
  ...acc,
  [e.employeeId]: (acc[e.employeeId] + 1) || 1,
}); 

const arr3 = Object.entries([...array1, ...array2].reduce(reducer, {}))
  .map(([employeeId, count]) => ({ employeeId, isActive: count == 2 }));
  
console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: Please verify whether the questionaior has specified his logic correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting your question as "If an `employeeId` is present in both arrays then *true*, otherwise *false*".

This is solvable by building a *Map*. You may even be able to continue working with the map after, rather than converting back into an *Array* at the end

```js
// Set up the initial Map using `array1`'s values, assume everything is different
const employeeStatus = new Map(
  array1.map(({ employeeId }) => [employeeId, false]),
);

// if `array2` has the same employeeId then set `true`, otherwise add a false entry
array2.forEach(({ employeeId }) => {
  // for something more complex, you could also do some other logic here
  const seen = employeeStatus.has(employeeId);
  employeeStatus.set(employeeId, seen);
});


// convert the Map to the output data structure
const result = [...employeeStatus].map(([employeeId, isActive]) => ({
  employeeId,
  isActive,
}));
```

Which gives

```js
[
  { employeeId: 1997, isActive: false },
  { employeeId: 19, isActive: true },
  { employeeId: 191, isActive: true },
  { employeeId: 199, isActive: false },
  { employeeId: 1221, isActive: false },
]
```

Comment: Please vote to close the question. The asker doesnot have provided any attempts, the expected output and the logic are not matching. Does this needs to be answered?

Comment: @Nitheesh being sneaky and getting this answer in before the close, have voted

Comment: You could avoid answering these kind of questions to keep the community clean. The asker have not provided any valid attempts and even the expected output is not correct. This is like we have to work on a requirement where the asker has not attempted anything from their side.